# Adding labels to a Carto VL visualization?

Tags: labeling, carto, carto-vl

It was possible to add labels to polygon visualizations in Carto.js 3.x via the CartoCSS; is there a way to add them in Carto VL visualizations? From what I can tell, Carto VL doesn't have the CartoCSS styling options and I don't know what the alternative or workaround would be.

Answer (score 1):

With the new CARTO VL v1.1 we have just released, we added a new method to features called `getRenderedCentroid`. That allows creating a dynamic geojson layer, which then can be used to apply the common Mapbox GL labeling capabilities.

We have prepared a few examples in our Dev Center, such as this one: https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-point-labels

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I work at CARTO.

Unfortunately, there is not yet support for labels within CARTOVL. It's definitely on the team roadmap, but we need some time to figure out the best approach to implement this and for sure it will be properly announced very likely in CARTO's main [blog](https://carto.com/blog), but be sure to follow also our [`inside blog`](https://carto.com/blog/inside/).